# Can i use navigation for only the small view?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview

If i have a landscape view of 300/200 in an iPad, i want to use navigation for only the small view, is that possible? If yes, an example will be really helpfull

Comment: Please give more detail about what it is you are trying to do, this question is not clear at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
MainController *controller = [[MainController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
[controller release];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
navController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);
[navController release];
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: thanks a lot! i mean this is not the exact thing that i wanna do, but the logic really helps. The help is really appreciated.